# why doesn't c++ have an exponent operator?

Tags: c++, operators

is there a reason? i know there's POW(), but that's a function. why doesn't it have ^ for exponents, when it seems like a very simple thing too add, that would be very convenient

Comment: Why everyone is having problem with `pow` :P `^` is **bit-wise exclusive OR**

Comment: It's `pow`. POW would be a completely different thing (well, we can't be just things...).

Comment: Because they didn't put it in. You would have to ask Bjarne Stroustrup or the C++ committee, or Dennis Ritchie or the C committee. Anything you get here will be just more or less uninformed guesswork.

Comment: Highly speculative: There was no built in FPU available at design time

Comment: @DieterLücking On the contrary. The PDP-11 had a full array of FP instructions, and ditto the VAX.

Comment: It is explained in *The Design and Evolution of C++*, ch.11.6.1. "The original reason was that C doesn't have one..." and more.

Answer (score 0):

C++'s operators are modeled after C's operators which in turn are modeled after general machine code instructions.  The later have addition, subtraction, shift, and , or , xor *etc*.  They can have multiplication and perhaps even division.  All handle integers are handled and sometimes even floating-point numbers too.  But it would extremely rare for exponentiation to have direct processor support.  So it's never been thought of as (and so therefore wasnever made into) a builtin operator. Having said all that, there's left-shift `<<` which exponentiates powers of 2.

Comment: It isn't 'extremely rare'. The most commonly used processor family has had such an instruction for decades. I was using it on the PDP-11 in the 1970s, which is what C was built on.

Answer (score -2):

In some languages ^ is the sign of logical operation. I think is XOR operation.

So that is why you should use POW() in C++.

Comment: So? They could use `**` like some languages do.

Comment: More important than what it is in other languages is that it's also bitwise XOR in C/C++.

Comment: I saw that sneaky edit

Comment: Lol :) better edited than wrong.

Comment: This really isn't a reason. -1

Comment: ... So should I edit again and write it wrong?

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean, but you should give a reason that is at least plausible.

Comment: Saying that the operator was already taken is not enough?

Comment: No, it isn't enough. The operator *symbol* was taken, but, as @Barmar's comment indicates, there are other choices.